# Solution for popup with some requirements in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Note: These should be done in the wordpress.

1. popup having the Mandatory fields with Mobile No and Email Id.

2.The user should not go into  the index page without entering with Mandatory fields.

3.After submit button is clicked, then thanks message should reach on the given mobile number.

4.After clicking to the submit button the popup should disappear automatically and can go to the index page.

Please help me out as soon as possible.